# How to get image dimensions when is stored in azure blob storage?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have image in blob and I want to read image dimensions (width and height)

This is my function to read from blob:

```
 private static CloudBlockBlob ReadBlockBlob(string input, IConfigurationRoot config)
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(
            new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(config["storageAccountName"], config["storageKeyValue"]), true);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(config["blobContainer"]);
        return container.GetBlockBlobReference(input);
    }
```

I don't see any useful metadata in CloudBlobContainer nor in CloudBlockBlob.

Any idea how to get dimensions of image from blob?

Thank you

Comment: I mean dimensions

Comment: It's better to save that information as metadata when you create the blob. I don't know if there is a way to get the information without just pulling the entire image and using GDI.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not directly get the dimensions of an image blob that exists on Azure Storage via the properties and metadata of the blob. The only way is to download the image blob and convert it to [`System.Drawing.Image`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netframework-4.7.2) via methods `System.Drawing.Image.FromFile` or `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream` to get `Image.Width` & `Image.Height`.

Or else, you need to first add metadata to the blob to store the image dimensions when uploading an image. Then, you can get the dimensions of an image from the blob metadata without downloading. I recommend this way to avoid downloading for those large images.